# How to get a list of all pending assignments under all courses in Moodle using the Web service API

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to get a list of all assignments along with their completion status under all courses. **Basically what is shown under the timeline in the dashboard.**

The WS function `core_course_get_enrolled_courses_by_timeline_classification`, gives me all the current courses the student is enrolled in when I use the parameter `?classification=inprogress`.

Using the course ids from the above function, I pass them as parameters to the function `mod_assign_get_assignments`, but there's just one tiny problem, it doesn't give any information on whether that assignment has been marked as complete by the student (completion status).

The function `core_course_get_contents` is a lot more than what I need since it provides every single module in that course and all activities under each module, moreover it gives all this only for one course at a time, however it does give the completion status for each activity.

> Also, it would help me out a lot if you provide the required and optional query parameters since the API docs are quite terrible and doesn't provide any of that, I had to google each function which was very time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest function I can see is `core_completion_get_activities_completion_status`

You can pass the course id and the user id

Which returns with a list of activities including

```
'cmid'          => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'course module ID'),
'modname'       => new external_value(PARAM_PLUGIN, 'activity module name'),
'instance'      => new external_value(PARAM_INT, 'instance ID'),
'state'         => new external_value(PARAM_INT,
                            "Completion state value:
                                0 means incomplete,
                                1 complete,
                                2 complete pass,
                                3 complete fail"
                            ),
'timecompleted' => new external_value(PARAM_INT,
                            'timestamp for completed activity'),
```

So in your code, filter the result for `modname = 'assign'`

The id in the `mdl_assign` table is the `instance` id

Comment: This would be the closest to what i'm looking for but it only allows a single course id as parameter meaning i'll have to make this request multiple times. Is there a function where I can give an array of course ids as parameters (Like in the `mod_assign_get_assignments` function)?